# Issue with tsc --build: useContext not working in generated files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, compilation, tsconfig, tsc

I'm encountering a problem with my code after running "tsc --build." I have two files, menus.jsx and useMenus.js:

```
// menus.jsx:
import React, { createContext } from "react";
export const MenuContext = createContext();
export const MenuProvider = ({ children, menus = [] }) => {
    return <MenuContext.Provider value={{ menus }}>{children}</MenuContext.Provider>;
};
```

.

```
// useMenus.js:
import { useContext } from "react";
import { MenuContext } from "../context/menus.jsx";

const useMenuContext = () => {
    const context = useContext(MenuContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error(
            "No menu context found. Have you configured the provider?"
        );
    }
    return context;
};

export const useMenu = (name = "") => {
    const { menus } = useMenuContext();
    if (!name) {
        throw new Error(
            "[useMenu] Missing name argument"
        );
    }
    return menus.find((menu) => menu.name === name).items || [];
};
```

Everything works perfectly when I import useMenu and call it. However, after compiling my files using "tsc --build" and importing the generated file, I get the error: "context is undefined: No menu context found. Have you configured the provider?"

Other files are working well, but only the ones that use useContext from React are not working. This is my tsconfig.json config:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declarationDir": "./types"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I've checked imports, exports, naming, data, etc., but i get errors only with files that use: import { createContext } from "react". not only this file.
Any ideas?